# Radsearchbox not displaying selected text

Tags: asp.net, search, telerik, rad

I am using radsearchbox in my application. The data source is working and showing the values in dropdown but when I select an item in the dropdown the textbox is not populating. My code is

```
<telerik:RadSearchBox ID="RadSearchBox1" runat="server" 
        Filter="StartsWith" EnableAutoComplete="true" DataTextField="Name">

    </telerik:RadSearchBox>
```

and in code

```
string comtext = "select Name from tblcustomer";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comtext, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        RadSearchBox1.DataSource = ds;
        RadSearchBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What wound up being your solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be that you are not using a `SearchContext`.  But I think that you just need to specify the key field for the search box.  Note below, the parameter `DataValueField` pointed at the ID for your table. (Change to your particular table id field)

```
<telerik:RadSearchBox ID="RadSearchBox1" 
                      runat="server"
                      DataTextField="Name" 
                      DataValueField="TableID" >
</telerik:RadSearchBox>
```

You would also need to change your query string to include the ID in the dataset.

```
string comtext = "select Name, TableID from tblcustomer";
```

[Telerik's RadSearch demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/searchbox/examples/search-context/defaultcs.aspx) can give examples of how to use `SearchContext` if needed.

Comment: I am using 2013 version. When I added the search context it gives error that search context is not supported.

Comment: @HasanZubairi, search context just puts the drop down next to the search bar to try to limit your results more effectively.  What happened when you just added the datavaluefield?

Comment: nothing is working. I have added id field in the database and I have added datatextfield and datavaluefield but that does not work. Like if i type b the list shows names with b but when i click on a name in the dropdown it is not populating the text input field.

Comment: @HasanZubairi Check out [the project attached to this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/set-search-text-from-server-side).

Comment: @HasanZubairi, do you have any more information based on what I've given here?